# Node npm Unirest gives stale/old data

Tags: node.js, npm, unirest

I am using Unirest middleware from inside my node js script to make a GET request. However for some reason I am getting stale/old data from the resource being requested.

Even after updating the data, I am getting stale data from the resource.
Here's the code :

```
let unirest = require('unirest');
unirest.get('<resource_url>')
.headers({"cache-control": "no-cache"})
.end(function (response) {
   console.log('body===>',JSON.stringify(response.body));
   console.log('status=====>',response.status);
   console.log('response headers=====>',response.headers);
});
```

response headers=====> { 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains ',
  date: 'Fri, 15 Sep 2017 18:58:40 GMT',
  cached_response: 'true',
  'cache-control': 'no-transform, max-age=3600',
  expires: 'Fri, 15 Sep 2017 12:10:53 GMT',
  vary: 'Accept,Accept-Encoding',
  'content-length': '1383',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-language': 'en-US' }

The same resource gives updated data instantly when tried via Python scipt or CURL.

Note : After some time say 3hrs, the node js script gives updated data.